# Длина строки из символов различных кодировок

Tags: php, строки

Для строки `"hello"`, `strlen` вернет `5`
Для `"привет"` - вернет `12`
Для `"приветR"` - вернет `13`

Есть ли универсальное решение для точного определения длины строки с заранее неизвестными типами кодировок? А то я уже налепил типа этого:

```
$len = strlen(iconv("UTF-8","windows-1251",$string)
```

Главное, что работает. Но, по-моему, это просто костыль какой-то.

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.mb-strlen.php

Comment: @eicto, не работает. То же самое

Comment: @eicto, аа, вы имели в виду второй параметр установить?

Спасибо! Я совершенно неграмотный!

Comment: @Deus, если Вы нашли решение - пожалуйста, оформите его в виде ответа - это необходимо для улучшения структуризации содержимого ресурса.

Comment: @soon, как я могу решение, которое предоставил eicto, оформить в виде своего ответа? Это уже плагиат какой-то...

Comment: Это не проблема, сейчас мы его позовем: @eicto

Comment: Я не знаю как тут дать развернутый ответ.

Comment: @eicto, можете написать, что существует функция, принимающая опциональным параметром кодировку. В любом случае, дать ответ лучше, чем оставить его в комментариях, иначе он потом опять всплывет.

Comment: Воь сами и напишите.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*<sup>На основании ответа @eicto из комментариев к вопросу</sup>*

Существует функция [`mb_strlen`](http://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.mb-strlen.php), принимающая опциональным параметром кодировку:

```
mixed mb_strlen ( string $str [, string $encoding = mb_internal_encoding() ] )
```